# Likelihood A>B, Given Margin of Errors For A and B

Tags: sampling

Let's say in a video game there are 2 different attacks I want to test, A and B. They have a RNG component so damage varies from one sample to next. Both follow a standard distribution. I test by taking a huge number of samples of each, find the mean, and calculate margin of error. Now I have all this, what do I do with this information? I want to know the chance A deals more damage than B on average.

This isn't like polling in a head to head electoral race, where people who actually don't vote for A will vote for B because B is the only other option. True value of A and B are unrelated and just have an average value from running many samples and a calculated margin of error.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be assuming independence.  But you also need the distributions, either observed or assumed  (if they are discrete then possibly A and B may be equal)

Comment: Do you mean margin of error or sample standard deviation?

Comment: As a reference, if $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, $s$ is the sample standard deviation and $n$ is the sample size, then the margin of error is $1.96 * s / \sqrt{n}$. This assumes the Normal distribution but you seem comfortable with that assumption (I guess that's what you mean by standard distribution).

Comment: Yes, assume it is normal distribution. I understand 1.96*s/SQRT(n) gives me margin of error. I have already calculated the standard deviation and margin of error for A and B. But once I have estimates for both of those and their MOE, I don't know how to compare them. If A is 1000 +/- 1% and B is 950 +/- 1%, how do I know the probability A>B?